# Check number of checkboxes depending on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have this following checkbox on my page

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Product Show</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="edprodShow" value="1" >Shape<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="edprodShow" value="2" >Color<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="edprodShow" value="3" >Design<br>
</div>
```

I would get values like 1 or 2 or 3(Externally, like in a JSON and i would extract that data).  I want to set first check box if 1 and 1st and 2nd if two check box and all three if I get 3.(i.e) Get only shape for 1 and color + shape for 2 and color+shape+design for 3

I have tried many sources and ways but not finding the appropriate output how can I do it ?

Edit :

Code I tried to do

```
 if(split_data[7].toString() === "1"){

                    $('#edprodShow').prop('checked', true);

                    }else if(split_data[7].toString() === "2"){


                    }else if(split_data[7].toString() === "3"){

                        $('#edprodShow').prop('checked', true);
                    }
```

where split_data[7] gives me 1,2 or 3

Comment: Please show code that you have tried so we can support you finding issues and solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
Sample Json from server

```
var json = { edprodShow: [1,2,4]};
```

Code

```
var checker = function(data){
    $("[name='edprodShow']").attr('checked', false);
    $.each(data.edprodShow, function(i, value){
        $("[name='edprodShow'][value='"+ value +"']").attr('checked', true);
    }

}
```

Call the function

```
checker(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution dear ☺

you can do this by javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $checkboxes = $('#devel-generate-content-form td input[type="checkbox"]');

$checkboxes.change(function(){
    var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    // $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);

    $('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes').val(countCheckedCheckboxes);
})
```

Here you can see [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/damithz/ewf1tku8/)